# React to real-time notifications about question status changes

Tags: feature-request, notifications, android-app, stack-overflow-app

While typing out a non-trivial answer in the Stack Overflow Android app, the question was deleted, but the app did not notify me until I tried to submit my answer several minutes later. Waste of time, given the level of effort taken to write the answer, especially when code snippets are involved (which are difficult to write on mobile).

Had I been typing my answer via a desktop web browser instead, the page would have updated in real-time and displayed a warning message when the question was deleted.

Please make the mobile app react to real-time updates when the status of a question changes while viewing/editing/answering it, and then notify the user accordingly. Thanks.

I can see this would have to include things like:

- Questions being edited/deleted
- Questions being locked by the community
- Comments being edited/deleted
- etc.

Comment: I agree with you but I think at this point the mobile app is limited by the API.  I'm tempted to write my own service to supplement the app so we can actually get that kind of functionality not on the site, but right now...the API itself doesn't lend itself to easily poll that kind of information.

Comment: (It also doesn't help that app development has slowed to a near halt as of late.)

Comment: @Makoto What API is the desktop site using to get real-time updates, that is not available to mobile?

Comment: AFAIK, the desktop site *doesn't* use the API.  This is most evident in the question list and filtering you get when looking at the mobile app; you see a bunch of negatively-scored questions and poor questions on mobile whereas on the desktop, you see none of that noise.

Comment: The desktop uses [websockets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218343/how-do-the-stack-exchange-websockets-work-what-are-all-the-options-you-can-send) for real-time updates.

Comment: I figured as much, so why not have the mobile app use WebSockets as well? WebSockets are not exclusive to web browsers.